# What type of exception to throw

Tags: c#, exception

What typeo of exception would you throw from a readonly property when the object that is being used to return value is null

```
public class TestClass
{
    SomeObject obj;
    public string NameOfObject 
    {
       get 
       {
            if(obj == null)
            { // what exception type to throw here  }
            return obj.Name;
       }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a question for it's topic, but why throw one at all?

Comment: IMPORTANT Note: A property should (almost) NEVER throw an exception when being read. (InvalidOperation is one that you can tho). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k("SYSTEM.INVALIDOPERATIONEXCEPTION.%23CTOR");k(SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-".NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0");k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) is what I would use in this case, because the access to the property is not valid for the current state of the object.

According to MSDN documentation:
"The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."
also:
"InvalidOperationException is used in cases when the failure to invoke a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments."

In this case obj is not an argument, which is why I would **lean** towards "InvalidOperationException"

The reason why I would not throw a NullReferenceException here: If you didnt add any special code, thats the exception that ".Net" would throw, so why add redundant code?

Answer (score 10):

I would throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

`ArgumentNullException` i only throw if methods parameters are null.

If the methods parameter is in an invalid state i throw an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: If you do `new InvalidOperationException()` without passing your own message, the default message is "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.", which is exactly right.

Answer (score 4):

You should not throw NullReferenceException. It is reserved for situations when a null object is dereferenced. In this case, if you were to throw NullReference, you might as well just leave the null check out and let the framework throw it for you when you attempt to access the obj's Name.

I'd throw [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) instead.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why not using an NullReferenceException

Answer (score 3):

Everybody has covered the obvious, so here's another option.

If your class must be initialized in some manner (your `SomeObject` must be set at some point), consider implementing [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx).  This indicates to users of your class that it is not in a valid state prior to `EndInit()` being called.  Unfortunately, there is no preexisting general `NotInitializedException` you can use (there are some but are specific to certain namespaces), so I would suggest pairing your implementation of the interface with the creation of such an exception.

Users must first call `BeginInit()`, then configure the instance, then call `EndInit()`.  On the call to `EndInit()`, check the state of your instance.  If it is not correctly intialized, you can throw an InvalidOperationException.  If users attempt to use your instance prior to being initialized, you would throw your NotInitializedException.

Its a bit more work, but the advantage is that you are creating a wider "pit of success" for your users, ensuring they use your classes correctly by failing fast and early, and by the very definition of your type (the interface is pretty clear on what you expect).  It also give you more "room", so to speak, for documenting how your class should be used.

Comment: I am familiar with ISupportInitialize and its use in DI contexts (i.e. property injection). I'm not so sure that this jives so well as a  programmatic\user API. This pattern is used in WinForms and WPF a lot, but I would suspect few people are even aware of it, so not so sure about the 'pit of success' angle. This pattern is used in UI frameworks because of the need of a default constructor. In a user API this does not necessarily have to be the case, other mechanisms can be used to ensure that an object is created with the correct state e.g. constructor parameters and arg validation.

Comment: @chi all true.  Just figured that even after fifteen "InvalidOperationException" answers there was room for at least one alternate.  The pit is bigger, imho, because it forces users to "set up" the instance, which means users have to consider what this really means.  Its a bit clearer than this or that method/property throwing an exception if you haven't done something yet.

Comment: Agreed - I think there are better ways to solve the issue than throwing an "InvalidOperationException". I was also on the alternative solution angle.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're saying somewhere that this property will never be null, why would you need to throw an exception?

Having said that, if you have guaranteed that, I would throw an [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

`InvalidOperationException` is

> The exception that is thrown when a
>   method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

Answer (score 1):

I'd throw an `InvalidOperationException`, but only if:
- it is legal for `obj` to be `null`, and it is the user's responsibility to check for this, or
- it is not legal for `obj` to be `null` in the first place (i.e., `obj != null` is a class invariant)

If neither of the above is the case (that is, it is legal for `obj` to be `null`, and user code is not explicitly required to check for this before using the property), then I'd not throw at all but rather return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I would revisit the design so that this state cannot exist in the first place i.e. obj is null. Generally from an API perspective you should be able to call a getter in good faith that it will not blow up as a result of the object being in an unknown state.

For example, why not have 'SomeObject obj' as a constructor parameter and use argument validation at the point of construction. This will ensure that the state of 'obj' is always correct i.e. non-null after construction.

There are many patterns that can be used to ensure that an object has a correct state when it becomes available to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you provide and not knowing anything about your design assumptions I'd say that you should not test `obj == null` at all and let the framework throw a `NullReferenceException`. So why do you want this test? One reason I could think of is that you want to have a more meaningful error message for debugging, but then you should use `Debug.Assert(obj != null, "Your message here")`.